# Why are some optimisation options not available in my GCC build?

Tags: c++, mysql, c, gcc

I recently compiled my own GCC because I needed to build MySQL 5.1 and my Mac OS X uses LLVM, which caused errors. The MySQL documentation recommends to use

```
CFLAGS="-O3" CXX=gcc CXXFLAGS="-O3 -felide-constructors -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti"
```

but configuration breaks if I use them. The `configure` output shows, for instance:

```
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
```

If I don't use the flags, everything works fine and have a MySQL working but I was wondering if I'm missing some code optimisation... or maybe I built a buggy MySQL?

I built GCC 4.8.2 with GMP 5.1.3, MPFR 3.1.2, MPC 1.0.1, ISL 0.11.1 and CLooG 0.18.0. Am I missing something?

I hope you can help me understand all this. I just do web development and sometimes this software building details are hard to get. Always trying to learn though. Thanks!

Comment: can you compile `int main(){}` as c++ with gcc and those options? If not, perhaps file a bug with gcc.

Comment: Are you *sure* `gcc` is actually invoking your compiled gcc instead of the gcc wrapper provided by Apple? What does `gcc --version` show?

Comment: Version shows: `gcc (GCC) 4.8.2`. Used to be `Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)`

Comment: I'm very sorry, this is an embarrassing mistake. I used 0's (zeros) instead of O's in the optimisation flags. But `configure` still reports `gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no`. I guess my question now would be why this is happening? I'm glad it works now and I wonder why LLVM didn't stop because of the spelling error. Does it ignore unrecognised options? What should I do, edit the question? Thank you.

Comment: Please post the configuration options you used to build your own GCC. The output of `gcc -v` will do.

Comment: $ gcc-4.8 -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc-4.8
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.2/configure --program-suffix=-4.8 --with-gmp=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.2 --with-mpfr=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.2 --with-mpc=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.2 --with-cloog=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.2 --with-isl=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.2 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++ --enable-checking=release --disable-bootstrap
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)

Comment: I recompiled with a suffix and everything works as expected. Support shows "yes" now. I might have gotten confused with Apple's wrapper... I don't know. I think the suffix option was a better approach to avoid these mistakes. Learnt a lot, thanks!